# How to remove the trailing hyphen and add it in leading in dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-studio

**This is my input and I want the desired output, but i am not able to figure it out how to do it using dataweave**

Input:

"2000-"

Output:

"-2000"

Answer (score 2):

You may try this approach. It removes the last character, which is "-" and appends it back to the original string.

```
%dw 2.0
var in =  "2000-" //Input
output application/json
---
if (in endsWith "-") "-$(in[0 to -2])" else in

//Output: "-2000"
```

Please note that above approach works for this specific example, but you may need to adjust the logic if your requirements change.

Comment: Thanks @jarus, it is working for other examples as well